# Need pass dynamic url param value in massAction url of ui-component grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent, massaction, ui-grid

I have a massAction on a admin grid which need to pass URL parameter coming on the grid page like

> `http://ashish.local/admin/package_module/rsvp/index/event_id/21/key/e964d1eb362b02a9d6b3bf1281e5401966e71fb2b1fbb644b67db08f8aeef673/`

I need to pass the dynamic param **event_id** value as like 21 but dynamic as like coming URL of the grid

As I can pass `<param name="event_id">*</param>` then how to pass the url event_id to the ui-component massAction.
The * in the param is not converting to dynamic url as like below code of datasource of my grid

```
<dataSource name="rsvp_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Package\Module\Ui\Component\RsvpDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">rsvp_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">event_rsvp_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="event_id" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    <item name="status" xsi:type="string">1,0</item><!-- 1 = RSVP confirm -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Please help

Find below code for massAction:

```
<action name="confirm">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">confirm</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Confirm All</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="omnyfy_events/rsvp/massConfirm">
                <param name="event_id">*</param>
            </item>
            <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Confirm events RSVP</item>
                <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to confirm selected events RSVP?</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument
</action>
```

For reference please check below link:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-treemass.html

Here they have used static id in `<param name="status">2</param>` I need to fill this param with grid url param value dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my **`dataProvider`** class `Package\Module\Ui\Component\RsvpDataProvider`
in below segment:

```
<argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Package\Module\Ui\Component\RsvpDataProvider</argument>
```

I have inherited **`prepareUpdateUrl`** function of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider` class like below:

```
protected function prepareUpdateUrl() {
        if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
            return;
        }
        $this->objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical(print_r($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'], true));
        foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
            if ('*' == $paramValue) {
                $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
            }
            if ($paramValue) {
                $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                        '%s%s/%s', $this->data['config']['update_url'], $paramName, $paramValue
                );
                $this->objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical('$paramName: ' . $paramName . ' $paramValue:' . $paramValue);
                if ($paramName == 'status') {
                    $paramValue = explode(',', $paramValue);
                    $this->addFilter(
                            $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('in')->create()
                    );
                } else {
                    $this->objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical('rechead other');
                    $this->addFilter(
                            $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have customize my code by adding below condition 
**`if ($paramName == 'status')`**

Definitely this is not the best way to resolve the issue but as I am new to Magento2, I have no other way for resolve the issue.
Please let me know if anyone having better solution/suggestion for this